# YARN Application Stuck in ACCEPTED State with Cluster Resources Empty

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I'm experiencing an issue with my Hadoop YARN application where it remains in the ACCEPTED state and does not transition to RUNNING. After submitting my application, it seems to be added to the scheduler but not activated due to cluster resource constraints. Below is the command output and the diagnostic message I received:

`[gauss@master class]$ yarn app -status application_1699287500486_0001 2023-11-07 00:21:24,030 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8032 2023-11-07 00:21:24,520 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found 2023-11-07 00:21:24,521 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'. Application Report :  Application-Id : application_1699287500486_0001 Application-Name : Max temperature Application-Type : MAPREDUCE User : gauss Queue : default Application Priority : 0 Start-Time : 1699287603604 Finish-Time : 0 Progress : 0% State : ACCEPTED Final-State : UNDEFINED Tracking-URL : N/A RPC Port : -1 AM Host : N/A Aggregate Resource Allocation : 0 MB-seconds, 0 vcore-seconds Aggregate Resource Preempted : 0 MB-seconds, 0 vcore-seconds Log Aggregation Status : DISABLED Diagnostics : [周二 11月 07 00:20:03 +0800 2023] **Application is added to the scheduler and is not yet activated. Skipping AM assignment as cluster resource is empty.  Details : AM Partition = <DEFAULT_PARTITION>; AM Resource Request = <memory:2048, vCores:1>; Queue Resource Limit for AM = <memory:0, vCores:0>; User AM Resource Limit of the queue = <memory:0, vCores:0>; Queue AM Resource Usage = <memory:0, vCores:0>; ** Unmanaged Application : false Application Node Label Expression : <Not set> AM container Node Label Expression : <DEFAULT_PARTITION> TimeoutType : LIFETIME  ExpiryTime : UNLIMITED  RemainingTime : -1seconds`

I attempted to list the applications using `yarn app -list`, and here's the output:

`[gauss@master class]$ yarn app -list 2023-11-07 00:21:56,176 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8032 Total number of applications (application-types: [], states: [SUBMITTED, ACCEPTED, RUNNING] and tags: []):1 Application-Id      Application-Name        Application-Type          User           Queue                   State             Final-State             Progress                            Tracking-URL application_1699287500486_0001       Max temperature               MAPREDUCE         gauss         default                ACCEPTED               UNDEFINED                   0%                                     N/A`

There are no applications in the RUNNING state, but my application is not progressing beyond the ACCEPTED state. The ResourceManager's diagnostic message indicates that the AM assignment is being skipped because the cluster resource is empty.

Here's what I've checked so far:

- Cluster health and that the ResourceManager and NodeManagers are up and running.
- There are no other applications running that could be consuming resources.
- The resource-types.xml file is mentioned as not found, but it's unclear if this is a contributing factor.

**I'm unsure why the queue resource limits for AM are showing as zero and why the application's AM is not being allocated resources. Can anyone suggest what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it so that my YARN application can transition to the RUNNING state?
**
Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.